# Adding a value to existing value using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on a bank ATM project. The user can input a value to deposit or withdrawal. On click, the balance increases adding the input value to the initial balance. The information changes on the screen using DOM. All the variables are numbers. I can't get the input value to add to the existing value. Every time I click, the value resets.

I want to be able to decrease the balance onClick or increase the balance onClick. Below is the code I wrote to add to the balance.

In the html

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="account">
            <div class="account-name">Checking Account</div>
            <div class="balance">Checking Account Balance:</div>   
            <p id="demo">1000</p>
            <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
            <div><button id="checking-deposit-btn" class="deposit-btn">Deposit</button></div>
                <button id="checking-withdraw-btn" class="withdrawal-btn">Withdrawal </button>
            <div id="checking-error" >Checking Error: You have insufficient funds </div>
            </div>type here
```

In the javascript file

```
checkingAccountDepositBtn.addEventListener("click", depositFunction);
checkingAccountWithdrawalBtn.addEventListener("click", onRedButtonClick);

function depositFunction() {
    let balanceValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    console.log(balanceValue)
    let balance =1000
    
    
    balance += balanceValue;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = balance;
    console.log(balance)
}
```

If the user inputs 100 I want that to add to the balance. If the user inputs 200, it should add to the total. Instead it just resets, the value of the balance variable.

Comment: EVERY time you call your deposit function you set the balance to 1000!

Answer (score 1):

the balance variable that you are modifying only exists when you are calling the function to add or subtract the balance because it is declared within the function. This means that anything that you do outside of that function, you won't be able to access that variable because it is only within the scope of that function (more about scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)).

you should refactor your code to the following to get the desired behavior:

```js
checkingAccountDepositBtn.addEventListener("click", depositFunction);
checkingAccountWithdrawalBtn.addEventListener("click", onRedButtonClick);

let balance =1000

function depositFunction() {
    let balanceValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    console.log(balanceValue)
    
    balance += balanceValue;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = balance;
    console.log(balance)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the **balance variable** outside of the function. Otherwise every time you run the function the **balance** will be reset to **1000** + the **value** you've added.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the balance inside the function, which overrides the already existing balance. You can store the balance outside of the function and update it using the function:

```
let balance = 1000; // store initial balance outside of function

function depositFunction() {
    // rest of the code
}
```